# Removing script tags that are loaded by other script tag

Tags: hooks

I have a third party script tag that embeds a form that loads its own scripts and styles. The script tag's `src` points to a PHP file that contains javascript code which injects multiple script dependencies to the DOM. Those loaded scripts include jQuery among others, and since i already used WP's own jQuery i want to remove the third party jQuery script. I've tried `wp_head`, `wp_footer`, `the_content` hooks to no avail since they only gave me the original script tag before it loads the other scripts.

Is there a hook that deals with the final HTML after every script is downloaded and parsed? Then i could just do a filter by regex on it.

Also, the scripts when loaded are appended as `async` so that complicates things up. Is it possible to prevent the scripts to execute?

Comment: There's nothing you can do from the WordPress side. This is happening in the script you're loading so you'll need to ask the third party to see if this behavioru can be changed.

Comment: It'd help if you showed us `how` you were adding this third party script.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @TonyDjukic It's just a script tag that you paste wherever you want the form to be, the post content, footer, etc. The script's src points to a PHP file that contains javascript code which injects multiple script dependencies to the DOM.

Comment: If that's the case you'll need to speak the script developers and ask them to generate an alternative version that doesn't add an extra jQuery.